# Community curation of the blekko.com programming slashtags

Tags: discussion, community

Would you, the Stack Overflow programming community, be interested in **a community partnership with http://blekko.com?**

- http://blekko.com would like to tap the Stack Overflow community to help improve and maintain the programming-related [slashtags](http://blekko.com/tag/show).
- We'd like to identify interested folks from the Stack Overflow community to add as slashtag editors.  Blekko's community manager Cheralyn will facilitate the process of getting these folks set up to make edits.
- We will do mutual press around this, with headlines such as "Blekko taps Stack Overflow community to help curate programming and technology [slashtags](http://blekko.com/tag/show)."  We can talk about how Blekko turned to our community to help us edit all of these tags and curate the best programming search verticals, and how Stack Overflow has quickly risen to become the preeminent programmer community on the web.

(Blekko is also in the process of building a system to more comprehensively import our sitelist and improving crawl coverage for our sites.)

What do you guys and gals think? I know there are at least a few avid http://blekko.com users in our community, so this might be cool.

edit: now [formally announced on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/blekko-and-stack-overflow/), too

Comment: Excellent idea.  Where do we sign up.

Comment: @jzd just post a comment here or an answer below. Answers would be better, I would like to hear how people are using blekko.

Comment: @jzd what's your blekko username? And what sorts of slashtags might you be interested in?

Comment: It just 'feels good' to see this finally happen, thanks for seeing it through!

Answer (score 3):

That would be a fantastic idea. I'd be willing to help in the tags that I'm most active in. I really like what Blekko is doing, and I love finding information that I need without having to sift through a mountain of crud.

This sort of partnership just makes too much sense *not* to happen.

As for my use, I find the existing programming slashtags *ok enough* to get by, I've been working on my own. Additionally, I've been digging through Data Explorer to find interesting and useful blogs maintained by people I've come to respect in the tags that I participate on SO. It is my `/unicorn` slashtag, which gets me results from other SO/SE users.

For the most part, I use 'brand - x' search engine when I'm looking for an image or video. I use Blekko when I actually need to get work done.

Incidentally, several people have already created various combinations of SE sites in slashtags. The two tools go together quite well.

Comment: Tim, would you like to edit some of the existing blekko programming slashtags? For the most part they were just thrown together, and could use some love.

Comment: @Greg - Already on board. Half of the fun is re-visiting my bookmark archive to add sites to tags that only have a few listed.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough I came across Blekko today and tried to create a slashtag for Windows Phone 7 programming. I have found it difficult to keep Google search results narrowed in on WP7 or Silverlight specific topics, and Blekko sounded like it might help solve that problem. The one major flaw I could find was they currently don't do a very good job at returning search results from Stackoverflow.com. For example, try searching for "Tombstoning" using the [/WP7Dev slashtag](http://blekko.com/ws/tombstoning+/gbrayut/wp7dev) I made and compare it with the results from [Google](http://www.google.com/q=tombstoning+windows+phone+7) and from Stackoverflow using the [Windows Phone 7 tag](http://goo.gl/Bo4HH). This is just one example, and I really have't tried using it that much yet, but I do like the idea of a vertical search engine that returns only trusted results. WP7Dev might be too narrow of a topic, but if they can improve their results from Stackoverflow / StackExchange then it could end up helping out both sites. I think it would be very cool if we could use something like `/StackExchange/StackOverflow/Windows-Phone-7` as a slashtag on Blekko combined with other sites and blogs like I did for my [/WP7Dev slashtag](http://blekko.com/ws/+/view+/gbrayut/wp7dev). They do have limited support for [3rd party APIs](http://blekko.com/tag/show), so maybe they could look at using the StackApps API.

As for being a tag editor... I'm planning on testing a few niche slashtags like /WP7Dev and /RxNet (Reactive Extensions), but am not very interested in general /Programmer slashtags

Comment: I promoted /wp7dev to be a /blekko/ slashtag, and invited you to edit it. As for Tombstoning /wp7dev, one of the reasons we're still "beta" is that we haven't crawled all the pages on websites such as stackoverflow -- the one page I looked at the details of, we hadn't crawled. We have a new crawl/index coming up to production fairly soon.

Comment: @Greg Lindahl Thanks! I look forward to the new crawler and index. Love the idea of a search engine that can target specific verticals.

Answer (score 2):

I asked Blekko to create a /so tag yesterday for Stackoverflow, which has been added<strike>, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly as of yet.</strike> and is currently working.

I'm also an editor for that tag, see http://blekko.com/ws/+/view+/blekko/so

Answer (score 2):

It would be interesting to see what kind of semi-automated process could be used to leverage the SO (and other SE) corpus to do the curation (SO pages with the correct tags and enough votes, links off accepted and sufficiently upvoted answers of said questions, Links added by high scoring users, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This is a great idea. It would be awesome to see Blekko have better integration with Stack Overflow. I know they are consuming some stuff from the Twitter API (kind of cool be to able to do a "#dotnet /twitter" search). Something similar for Stack Exchange sites could be very useful.

The ability to build up slashtags that allow your search results to get better and more tailored to you is quite nice. I would love to be a part of anything that comes of this as I use Stack Overflow and Blekko just about daily for research and finding solutions (mostly programming related). I'm an editor on a few global tags and trying to curate a .NET one as I get time. Here is 
[my Blekko Profile](https://blekko.com/user/copenhas) for anyone interested or has site suggestions.

Generally my usage is mostly "<topic or question> /webdev" or /dotnet, but it's actually a pretty nice way to discover sites as you start to explore some of the global and user tags. The social aspect of being able to collaborate on slashtags to everyone's benefit is pretty cool.